# Codeigniter join statement with a join statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select, inner-join

I'm having an issue with converting the below statement into code on my model in the codeigniter framework.

```
SELECT mt_prs_groups.groupId, mt_prs_groups.groupName, mt_prs_administrators.administratorId
FROM mt_prs_status INNER JOIN (mt_prs_administrators INNER JOIN mt_prs_groups ON mt_prs_administrators.administratorId = mt_prs_groups.administratorId) ON (mt_prs_status.statusId = mt_prs_groups.statusId) AND (mt_prs_status.statusId = mt_prs_administrators.statusId)
WHERE (((mt_prs_status.status)="Active") AND ((mt_prs_administrators.administratorId)=3)) OR (((mt_prs_administrators.administratorId)=4));
```

On the model I have translated this to

```
$this->db->select('mt_prs_groups.groupId, mt_prs_groups.groupName');
$this->db->from('mt_prs_status');
$this->db->join('mt_prs_administrators', 'inner');
$this->db->join('mt_prs_groups', 'mt_prs_administrators.administratorId = mt_prs_groups.administratorId AND mt_prs_status.statusId = mt_prs_administrators.statusId', 'inner');
$this->db->where('mt_prs_status.status="Active"');
$this->db->where('mt_prs_administrators.administratorId=3');
$this->db->or_where('mt_prs_administrators.administratorId=4');
```

This is giving me the error below

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'inner' in 'from clause'
>
> SELECT `mt_prs_groups`.`groupId`, `mt_prs_groups`.`groupName` FROM
>   `mt_prs_status` JOIN `mt_prs_administrators` USING (`inner`) INNER
>   JOIN `mt_prs_groups` ON `mt_prs_administrators`.`administratorId` =
>   `mt_prs_groups`.`administratorId` AND `mt_prs_status`.`statusId` =
>   `mt_prs_administrators`.`statusId` WHERE `mt_prs_status`.`status` =
>   "Active" AND `mt_prs_administrators`.`administratorId` = 3 OR
>   `mt_prs_administrators`.`administratorId` = 4

The query runs well when I put it directly on mysql but fails in codeigniter. The issue is the inner join is dependent on another inner join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this .I tried this into codeigniter

```
$this->db->select('mt_prs_groups.groupId, mt_prs_groups.groupName');
$this->db->from('mt_prs_status');
$this->db->join('mt_prs_administrators', 'mt_prs_status.statusId = mt_prs_administrators.statusId','inner');
$this->db->join('mt_prs_groups', 'mt_prs_administrators.administratorId = mt_prs_groups.administratorId', 'inner');
$this->db->where('mt_prs_status.status="Active"');
$this->db->where('mt_prs_administrators.administratorId=3');
$this->db->or_where('mt_prs_administrators.administratorId=4');
```

Comment: This did it for me...thank you so much for this. I see where i went wrong with my query

Comment: Pleasure is mine :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this format

```
 $this->db->select('tbl_tasks.task_id,tbl_tasks.task, tbl_assign_task.user_id');
        $this->db->from(TBL_TASKS);
        $this->db->join(TBL_ASSIGN_TASK, 'tbl_tasks.task_id = tbl_assign_task.task_id');
        $this->db->where('tbl_assign_task.is_deleted', 0);
         $this->db->where('tbl_assign_task.user_id', $userId);
        $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: thing is its a join within a join. `mt_prs_status` is joining another join statement

Answer (score 0):

In this line - "$this->db->join('mt_prs_administrators', 'inner');" you are not defining joining condition, that's why you are getting an error because the format of the join in CI is - 
$this->db->join('table_name', 'column name on which we apply the join', 'type of join');

Comment: The issue is how do I write that query into codeigniter. The `mt_prs_status` joins another join statement  this one `(mt_prs_administrators INNER JOIN mt_prs_groups ON mt_prs_administrators.administratorId = mt_prs_groups.administratorId) ON (mt_prs_status.statusId = mt_prs_groups.statusId) AND (mt_prs_status.statusId = mt_prs_administrators.statusId)` and in this 2nd statement is a join. So the issue is not the error perse but rather how do I right that statement

Comment: Please look at the statement and try to write it into codeigniter